# HTML validations not working in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, validation, html

I have put in some client side validations in my VF page using "required = true" for an input tag. However, on clicking the "**Create Campaign**" command button, these are not enforced and I am directly been taken to the controller method. Below is relevant parts of my code.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" Controller="ImportCampaignsAngularPoCCntrl" showHeader="true" title="Import CR Campaigns" >
<apex:form>
<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!initialiseMandatoryFieldsBlock}" reRender="requiredFieldsBlock,hiddenBlock">
        <apex:param id="mandatoryfield" name="mandatoryfieldwrapper" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
         <apex:actionFunction id="setState" action="{!insertCampaignToDb}" 
      name="setState" reRender="requiredFieldsBlock,hiddenBlock" >
      </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:actionFunction id="goBack" action="{!back}" name="goBack" 
    reRender="requiredFieldsBlock,hiddenBlock">
      </apex:actionFunction>
           <apex:outputpanel id="requiredFieldsBlock">
  <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.MandatoryFieldsPrompt}" rendered="{!isCampaignSelected}">
  <apex:pageBlockTable id="fieldsTable" title="Mandatoryfields" value="{!MandatoryFieldsWrapperList}" var="mandatoryFieldWrapper">

    <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.MandatoryFields}" value="{!mandatoryFieldWrapper.fieldLabel}" style="width:500px; height: 28px; text-align:center"/> 

    <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.Value}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!campaignToInsert[mandatoryFieldWrapper.fieldApi]}" required="true" style="width: 600px; height: 28px" />
    </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  <apex:commandButton onclick="setState()" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-around--large" reRender="requiredFieldsBlock,hiddenBlock" status="renderLightningSpinner" value="Create Campaign"/>
  <apex:commandButton onClick="goBack()" html-novalidate="novalidate" immediate="true" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-around--large slds-float--right" reRender="errorMessageBlock,hiddenBlock" status="renderLightningSpinner" value="{!$Label.Back}"/>
     </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:pageBlock id="hiddenBlock" rendered="false"></apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
    </apex:page
```

**Controller method**

```
   public PageReference insertCampaignToDb() {

    system.debug('Inside InsertCampaigntoDB');
    system.debug('crAccountID---->'+crAccountId); 
    system.debug('Generic campaignToInsert inside insertCampaignToDb---->'+campaignToInsert);   
    campaignToInsert = (Campaign)campaignToInsert;
    finalCampaign = (Campaign)campaignToInsert;
    system.debug('finalCampaign inside insertCampaignToDb----->'+finalCampaign);
    try {
        DMLManager.insertAsUser(finalCampaign);
        system.debug('Inside try block---->');
        PageReference campaignPage = new PageReference('/' + finalCampaign.id);
        campaignPage.setRedirect(true);
        return campaignPage;
    }        
    catch(DMLManager.CRUDException crudExep) {
        system.debug('Inside Catch block for CRUDException');
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,Label.CrudExpInsertCampaigns));
        LoggerRepository.createErrorLog(finalCampaign.crAccount__c,Label.CrudExpInsertCampaigns,crudExep.getMessage(),crudExep.getStackTraceString());
        throw new loli_utils_Exceptions.CrudException(Label.CrudExpInsertCampaigns);
    }
    catch(DmlException dmlExep) {
        system.debug('Inside Catch block for DMLEXception');
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,Label.DmlException));
        LoggerRepository.createErrorLog(finalCampaign.crAccount__c,Label.DmlException,dmlExep.getMessage(),dmlExep.getStackTraceString());
       throw new DmlException(Label.DmlException);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't set `docType="html-5.0"` on your `<apex:page>` tag. I'd start with that.

Comment: I have added that tag. However it fires validation "Please fill out this field" only for a split second. After, it then directly takes to the controller action method

Comment: I have gone the route of ActionFunction as the commandbuttons werent invoking my action methods directly via "action" attribute.